# How to generate an order index value (as in the order of a list) in a SELECT statement

Tags: sql, oracle

Suppose I have these two tables :

```
TABLEA          TABLEB
-----------     -----------
ID  | NAME      ID | TABLEA_ID  | NAME
1   |  ...      1  | 1          | ...
2   |           2  | 2          | ...
3   |           3  | 2          |
4   |           4  | 2          |
                5  | 3          |
                6  | 3          |
                7  | 4          | 
                8  | 2          |
```

I want an `SQL SELECT` statement that can generate such result when `TABLEA.ID = TABLEB.TABLEA_ID`, you can note here I don't care about grouping or ordering, I just want to generate a **incremented value** for each line of the **same** `TABLEB.TABLEA_ID`.

```
ID | TABLEA_ID | ORDER_INDEX | NAME 
1  | 1         | 0           | ...  
2  | 2         | 0           | ...  
3  | 2         | 1           |      
4  | 2         | 2           |      
5  | 3         | 0           |      
6  | 3         | 1           |      
7  | 4         | 0           |      
8  | 2         | 3           |
```

I tried without success to use `rownum` in several combination of sub-selects to generate the `ORDER_INDEX` depending on the value in TABLEA_ID.

- Do you have hint to do that in plain SQL, is it even possible with plain SQL.
- Is it possible via a PL/SQL ? And how if possible ?

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that this is what you want:

```
SELECT B.ID, B.TABLEA_ID, 
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY B.TABLEA_ID ORDER BY B.ID) - 1 ORDER_INDEX,
       B.NAME -- OR A.NAME, its not clear on your question
FROM TABLEB B
LEFT JOIN TABLEA A
ON B.TABLEA_ID = A.ID
```

Comment: Thx this is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you very much. Thx to others too :)

Comment: Oh by the way your answer had a small error, as `rownumber` or `row_number()` always return numbers starting with 1, I had to apply a minus operation `ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY B.TABLEA_ID ORDER BY B.ID) -1 AS ORDER_INDEX`. Anyway thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

Something like this:

```
SELECT
    TableB.ID,
    TableB.TableA_ID,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY TableB.TableA_ID ORDER BY TableB.TableA_ID) AS ORDER_INDEX,
    TableB.Name
FROM
    TableA
    JOIN TableB
        ON TableA.ID=TableB.TableA_ID
ORDER BY TableB.ID
```

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY TABLEA_ID ORDER BY ID ASC) AS ORDER_INDEX
```

as the definition of ORDER_INDEX